# How can I share jest mocks between multiple tests?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a mock version of the `aws-sdk`, which works fine in my tests:

```js
jest.mock("aws-sdk", () => {
  return {
    Credentials: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
    Config: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn(),
    },
    S3: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      getSignedUrlPromise: awsGetSignedUrlMock,
    })),
    SQS: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
  };
});
```

However many of my tests use the mock AWS SDK, and I would like to not repeat the mock code unnecessarily. If I move the function into a separate file and import it, however, this will fail:

In my `testSupport.ts` file:

```js
export const mockAwsSdk = () => {
  return {
    Credentials: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
    Config: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
    config: {
      update: jest.fn(),
    },
    S3: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      getSignedUrlPromise: awsGetSignedUrlMock,
    })),
    SQS: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({})),
  };
};
```

In the test file:

```js
jest.mock("aws-sdk", mockAwsSdk);
```

This fails with:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'testSupport_1' before initialization
```

I have tried various solutions, including making a parent function that takes the `jest` instance, but I still haven't been able to get this to work.

**How can I share jest mocks between multiple tests?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jest has a [`moduleNameMapper` config property](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) which can be used to specify a string or regular expression to match your import and replace it with a mock file

Alternatively, you can add mocks without specifying it in the `moduleNameMapper` by [placing your mock file in a folder named `__mocks__`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) which should be in the same directory as the file you need to mock

In case it is in node_modules, the `__mocks__` folder should be in your parent directory.

Comment: Thanks Varun! I fixed the links so they don't read as 'here' but this is perfect!

Comment: Is there a way to change a mock in one of the tests?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved my problem using [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfiles-array).

Create a `jest.config.js` file:

```
const config = {
  setupFiles: ['./src/setupFiles.js']
}

export default config
```

Then you can write your shared mocks in `setupFiles.js`

```
import { Logger } from 'from-some-package'

jest.spyOn(Logger, 'init').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
jest.spyOn(Logger, 'info').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
jest.spyOn(Logger, 'debug').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())
jest.spyOn(Logger, 'error').mockImplementation(() => jest.fn())

jest.mock('third-party-package');

global.fetch = jest.fn()
```